# django graphene rate limit (throttling)

Tags: throttling, rate-limiting, graphene-django

I am building a REST Api on Django RF. I need to set a requests limit from IP. It's easy to do that for a regular Api endpoint in views.py just adding following settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '100/day',
        'user': '1000/day'
    }
}
```

But I also have a Graphene django for a graphql api.

How can I set up a rate limit for that view? I have tried django-ratelimit, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was solved by customising GraphQL view to the following:

```
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView


class CustomGraphQL(GraphQLView):
    def parse_body(self, request):
        if isinstance(request, Request):
            return request.data
        return super().parse_body(request)

    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        view = super().as_view(*args, **kwargs)
        view = authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication,))(view)
        view = throttle_classes((AnonRateThrottle, AnonMinutesThrottle,
                                 AnonSecondsThrottle, UserRateThrottle))(view)
        view = api_view(['GET', 'POST'])(view)
        return view
```

Comment: Have you tried to run this code? It raises 9 `not defined` errors.